# phonegap installed using npm in terminal has no output

Tags: cordova, npm

I'm trying to install phonegap. in phonegap.com/install it says:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

so I did it. After lots of package download it installs phonegap. when I run phonegap command, nothing happens:

```
phonegap
```

or

```
phonegap -v
```

nothing happens.

Comment: and what does `sudo phonegap`? I think the issue might be that using sudo when running npm does not add app to your user but to the su. I'd try running the npm command without sudo (sorry, not using debian here, so can't check)

Comment: 'sudo phonegap' does nothing.
I downloaded phonegap archive from another server (It's an old version), and It works. But the newest version can't be installed.

Comment: Have you tyied running `npm install -g phonegap` without the sudo?

Comment: Linux or Mac? What OS version? Also -- make sure node/npm is up-to-date.

Comment: 'npm install -g phonegap' doesn't change anything, the problem exists.
I'm using kubuntu 14.04 and every thing is up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution at [here](http://julianhigman.com/blog/2013/10/17/notes-on-setting-up-phonegap-on-ubuntu-for-android-app-development/)
I should've done this, before installing phonegap.

```
sudo npm update npm -g
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```